# Calling Sqoop in Spark program

Tags: apache-spark, sqoop

We have many ways to read/write data from Spark to external databases(Oracle, Teradata etc.), few popular choices are Spark JDBC, proprietary database connectors. **Is it possible to call Sqoop in Spark program ?** I don't want to create a separate job for data read/write.

Comment: From spark driver you can call any external process (installed on driver host) so running sqoop seems to be possible. But it is very inefficient, as sqoop will run mapreduce job on cluster with export task on data saved in spark... How sqoop is better that using proprietary jdbc inside spark job and writing data from Spark do Oracle/Teradata directly?

Comment: Sqoop is equally competitive compare to Spark JDBC. I am already using Spark JDBC to write data to Oracle but it is behaving slow so i want to try Sqoop without creating a separate job. I want to call Sqoop within the same Spark program. I mean i want to write the final dataframe to Oracle using Sqoop.

Comment: In this scenario spark will need to save dataframe in format that sqoop can read (for example with tab-delimited columns) on distributed storage before exporting. Then you can call standard sqoop process on this data from application code. But since this require additional step it wont be as efficient as spark JDBC so I really encourage you to remain with spark-jdbc and try to speed it up instead of using sqoop :-)